# Screen zoom (accessibility settings) not working, how to fix it?

Tags: 20.04, accessibility, zooming

I recently noticed(Ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS) that my screen zoom function is not working smoothly as it used to under Universal Access Settings. It does turns ON the screen zoom functionality but, it's very "laggy" and not smooth as it used to be. Any fix? Thanks.